# conflict exists with definition friendlist in namespace internal flex error

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4, flexbuilder

in my variable i am getting error

```
private var friendsList:VBox;
```

"conflict exists with definition friendlist in namespace internal" what it is ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you have an other definition with name `friendsList`. Just rename one of them.

Comment: i have no other defination of friendlist ,what may be other problem?

Comment: It can be `id` of some MXML component. Use `Ctrl+H` in Eclipse and search your project files with `friendsList` (try to do it not case sensitive).

Comment: yes in id i have use friendlist,do u think because of it i am getting error